# Doxygen fail to generate graphs in Linux

Tags: doxygen

I just tried to set up my Doxfile to generate graphs but i get:

```
Problems running dot: exit code=127, command='dot',
arguments='"/MyProject/extras/doc/target/html/_c_c_blade_8cpp__incl.dot" -Tpng -o
"/MyProject/extras/doc/target/html/_c_c_blade_8cpp__incl.png"'
finished...
*** Doxygen has finished
```

And no graphs are generated. Whats going on?

Comment: Without further information, all I can say is that doxygen tried to run the command dot with the above argument and the dot tool returned a exit code 127 instead of 0. Try running this command yourself from the command line, and/or provide more data (an example that has this result, the config file, the versions of doxygen and dot you used, etc...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem waas on Mint linux doxygen don't install plugins to draw graphs automatically, installing package graphviz solve the problem

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz -y
```

Comment: Additionally, to run `graphviz` to check it's correctly installed, use the CLI command `dot`